# How to re-run only the failed test cases with Junit test suite

Tags: junit

I'm new to Junit. I've created a test suite with 50 test cases. If I run it passes only 30 test cases and 20 test cases are failing. How I can achieve running only those 20 failed test cases again with the help of Junit? Is it possible? Can someone guide on this?

Comment: How do you run your test, in an IDE? In both IntelliJ and Eclipse I think there are options to run only failed tests.

Comment: @daniu I am using Android Studio. How to achieve in AS?

Answer (score 0):

Deciding which tests to run, and in which order, is the job of the *test runner*. So, to rerun only failed tests you need to use a test runner that records which tests passed or failed, and which can be instructed to run only tests it knows failed.

The tested runner in the Eclipse IDE can do this. Typically, and IDE is the only place you need this functionality, because an IDE is interactive and when using it you want fast feedback on whether a fix works. This functionality is not so useful elsewhere because in other contexts we typically want to check that the program passes *all* its tests.

Comment: Answer is on point, but not true.  You often need to run starting where you failed when runnign a large test suite e.g. from batch command.